# I wrote a code for wall jumping in unity 2d in Visual Studio but the method I created completely ignored the else if statement for wall jumping, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code for wall jumping I added it in the jumping method but the else if statement gets completely ignored and is not even implemented if the if statement is false:

[image]

Can you please tell me why?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the code itself into the post, not a picture of it!

Comment: Is `onwall()` returning the expected value? (the negated reevaluation of `isGrounded` is superfluous)